# how to remove question mark

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /domain.com/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /domain.com/$1.php [L]
```

am using this code for remove question mark but its not working, trying http://domain.com/details?id=71 to http://domain.com/details/id/71
Please help me where am wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is that first RewriteCond doing? If the request starts with 3 to 9 capital letters, followed by a space, matching atleast one of not anything (what?? `([^.]+)`), followed by .php?

Comment: @MikeB yes, so if the request is `GET /some-folder/some-file.php HTTP/1.1`, the `/some-folder/some-file` is captured and sent as a redirect

Comment: @JonLin The last rewriterule doesn't take care of that?

Comment: @MikeB The last rewrite rule is an internal rewrite, the first redirects the browser

Comment: the above code is removing .php extension but not ? and = so i ask what should i do for replace ? and = with /

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the first rewrite, but for the second (the last three lines), if the *incoming* URI is not an actual directory or file, you want to rewrite something like `details/id/71` to `/details.php?id=71`?

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$  /$1.php?$2=$3 [L]
```

should get you close, assuming there are always 3 fields. In a RewriteRule you don't put the domain name again.

Comment: the first Rewrite removing .php extension but am also trying to replace ? and = with / but its not working so can you guide me what should i really do?

Comment: Your _incoming_ URI is in the SEO form /details/id/71, and you're trying to rewrite it into a form that the server and PHP can handle: `/details.php?id=71`, right? You **can't** use .htaccess to go the other direction -- it doesn't even see _outgoing_ URLs.

Comment: ya you are right, its for SEO but what should i do, i confuse.

Comment: When you write your HTML links, e.g., `<a href="/details/id/71">click here</a>`. You have to do it at that point -- .htaccess does not process them.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't do anything remotely close to what you want. Your code simply removes the `php` extension when a request is made explicitly with the extension and adds it back internally. In order to make `http://domain.com/details?id=71` get redirected to `http://domain.com/details/id/71`, you need:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\s/+([^/]+?)(?:\.php|)\?([^=]+)=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$  /$1?$2=$3 [L]
```

you want this **before** your rules that remove the php extension

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jon but after using your above code .php come again and ? & = still appear.

Comment: @user3154050 I left out a `?` after the `[^/]+` pattern.

Comment: Sorry Jon but still it's not working, .php not removing after use above code and ? & = still appear :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your script is called details.php, the following single rule:

```
RewriteRule details/(.*)/(.*)/$ /details.php?$1=$2
```

Should rewrite www.domain.com/details/id/71 to www.domain.com/details.php?id=71

You don't need all that other stuff to remove the .php extension.